# Android multiple choice ListView doesn't display Checkmarks

Tags: java, android, listview, multiple-choice, checkmark

This is the xml for my ListView:

```
  <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
```

I want to display checkmarks when the user checks one item, but the checked box only changes its color to green and there's no checkmark. Why?

I can't post a picture because I haven't enough reputation.

Comment: `I can't post a picture because I haven't enough reputation.` You still can post a link to your picture.

Comment: in Listview activity use defalut `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

This will solve your problem
You can further learn : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode